# how to run linq on XxmlElement rather than XElement in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How to get the attributes of XmlElement rather than XElement in `C#` with `linq`?

```
public string test (XmlElement element)
{
     var enumAttr = from attr in element.Attributes select attr;

     foreach (var data in enumAttr)
      {
          // TO DO
      }
}
```

It's giving an error,

Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection'. 'Select' not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'attr'

Comment: "Its giving error" is *never* enough information. Please include the exact error message.

Comment: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection'. 'Select' not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'attr'

Comment: Please edit that into the question, and read http://tinyurl.com/so-list before asking your next question. It's important to give all relevant information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `XmlAttributeCollection` only implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. You *can* just change your query expression to:

```
var enumAttr = from XmlAttribute attr in element.Attributes select attr;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var enumAttr = from attr in element.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>() select attr;
```

But you're not really doing anything with the LINQ here anyway - you can just use:

```
foreach (XmlAttribute data in enumAttr.Attributes)
```